# Apache Tika version upgrade cause ClassCastException

Tags: java, scala, apache-tika, tika-server

I'm struggling with an issue(Java/Scala web project with Gradle), because I have to upgrade apache tika version to at least version **1.22, from 1.19.1**(previous version have security vulnerabilities). But when i try to change version(even to lower version) i receive an exception

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.apache.tika.config.TikaActivator for bundle org.apache.tika.core is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tika.config.TikaActivator cannot be cast to org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

I'm not using any configuration file, I have upgraded only the library(exception is thrown inside library, I have nothing in stacktrace reffering to my code). Version of tika dependencies are different, main concern is org.osgi:org.osgi.core upgrade from 4.0.0 to 6.0.0. I've forced in gradle to use version 4.0.0 in project, and i have received error, that *org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator* class is not found. The difference between classess according to documentation is additional annotation **@ConsumerType**. I think this is causing the problem. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What Apache Tika artifacts are you depending on? What OSGi framework are you using?

Comment: OSGi framweork - Equinox, i do not have any more dependencies from tika besides tika-core

Comment: I did some research and if i force org.osgi.core version of 4.0.0 (which is in tika-core before 1.20)instead of 6.0.0, i receive that class BundleActivator is not found. In their documentation i see, that difference between classess from 4 and 6 version differentiate by one annotation @ConsumerType. Is is possible that this is causing that Exception?